# How can I get a list of the exponents of a polynomial?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a polynomial 1 + x^2 + x^4 + x^8 + x^9.  I want a list of the exponents. 
{0,2,4,8,9}.

Comment: He is asking for Exponents not coefficients

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try:

```
  Exponent[1 + x^2 + x^4 + x^8 + x^9, x, List]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go!

```
Flatten[StringCases[
  StringCases["1 + x^2 + x^4 + x^8 + x^9", "x" ~~ __], DigitCharacter]]
```

Now here is one you can use later:

```
Flatten[StringCases[
  StringCases["polynomial goes here", "variable goes here" ~~ __], DigitCharacter]]
```

Comment: And where is the `0` ???

Comment: @eldo sorry, I couldn't figure out how :(